# Queue overflowed при выполнении кода

Tags: python, windows

Существуют две директории, первая содержит ряд папок с файлами, а вторая набор файлов. Необходимо на их основе создать третью, для этого в неё сначала копируется содержимое первой директории, а затем в каждую подпапку копируется содержимое второй. Таких директорий нужно создать n-ое количество. Осуществляется это следующим кодом на питоне:

```
import os
import distutils.dir_util
import distutils.file_util

def dir_list(root):
    return [ dir for dir in os.listdir(root) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, dir)) ]

def copy_tree(src, dst):
    distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(src, dst)

subd_list = []
paths = []

# здесь идет генерация имен и создание директорий

for path in paths:
    if os.path.exists(path):
        distutils.dir_util.remove_tree(path)
    copy_tree(subd_list[1], path)
    print path
    for dir in dir_list(path):
        copy_tree(subd_list[2], os.path.join(path, dir))
        print os.path.join(path, dir)

# далее в подпапках генерируется еще ряд файлов
```

В целом код работает как нужно, но на этапе копирования содержимого директорий и создания файлов в них винда начинает выдавать сообщения "`queue overflowed`". Сталкиваюсь с таким впервые и понятия не имею, как это обойти.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Дело не в питоне и не в винде, сообщения выдавал notepad++ с открытым рабочим пространством, в котором все действия и происходили.